# Spark takes 0.5 second to average 100 numbers

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, average

I've a dataset of about 70 millions rows in CSV of users locations and date times, and wrote the following code to average the number of points of top 100 users:

```
val spark = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder
    .appName("Test")
    .getOrCreate

import spark.implicits._

val watch = new Stopwatch()
watch.start()
val schema = new StructType().add("user_id", StringType).add("datetime", LongType)

val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").schema(schema).csv(inputFile)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("paths")

val pathDs = spark.sql("select user_id, min(datetime) as started, max(datetime) as finished, " +
    "count(*) as total, max(datetime) - min(datetime) as timeDelta " +
    "from paths group by user_id order by total desc limit 100")

pathDs.cache()
pathDs.collect.foreach(println)
println(watch.elapsedTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
val avgPoints = pathDs.select(avg("total")).as[Double].head()
println(avgPoints)
println(watch.stop())
```

What happens here is that I take millions/billions of records (which might eventually take terabytes), and aggregate them into 100 records of 5 columns. The question is not about how long this part takes or how we can speed it up, but rather what happens when we work with the resulting 100 records.

There's also a simpler way to do this straight up via SQL, but I also need the pathDS for more processing later on. The code works fine, but I noticed that `pathDs.select(avg("total")).as[Double].head()` starts doing a lot of work and ends up taking around half a second, even though pathDS only contains 100 rows.

Do you know why it's taking that long and how can I speed this up, specifically while operating on this small data set which is only 100 rows? I specifically do .cache and .collect on it to bring up all 100 records locally before I do any further aggregation (and I'm running this locally right now anyway).

I'm using Spark 2.2 on Scala 2.11, locally.

Comment: I'm not processing small data here - the full datasets will be in hundreds of gigabytes/TBs.  But I specifically want to see why this specific example is slow, as I thought that doing  .cache() should keep my 100 row dataset in memory and the results out of it should come out instantaneously.

Comment: I recommend checking out some of the advanced metrics in the SparkUI, to figure out why it's taking so long. I also recommend running at least one more dataset through this code, say with 1000 values, so you can better extrapolate constant overhead vs actual (O(n)) computation time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark optimizes for large data sets. This means that often there are some overheads which are negligible for large data sets but not so negligible for small ones.

Consider what happens when you run calculate avgPoints:

1. Spark calculates a "transformation", i.e. it defines what calculation needs to be done (this is the portion of the select, avg etc.).
2. You call the "head" action which causes spark to take the expression tree you made and turn it into a physical plan. This includes optimizations as well as comparing several possible solutions. Note that the expression also includes the expression of calculating the cached portion. In practice, those steps would be skipped (you can see this in the spark UI) but they are still considered as spark might decide in certain cases to recalculate some of the cached data (almost certainly not in this case).
3. Spark compiles the physical plan into code using whole stage code generation, serializes this code and sends it to all relevant executors.
4. When spark created the plan it partitioned the data (probably 200 partitions as that is the default for a groupby). This means that you have 200 tasks divided between your executors. Most partitions will have 0 or 1 elements so the task they do will be almost immediate but spark has to start 200 tasks.
5. Spark sends the result from each of the 200 tasks to a buffer and they are all sent to a single executor to do the final aggregation. The final aggregation task doesn't begin until all tasks finished and sent their data.
6. Once the final aggregation finishes, the result would be send back to the driver.

As you can see there are many stages here including network transmission and starting/ending tasks (which need to be managed). The overall overhead here can easily get to half a second even with no real data.

If you change the limit to 1000 instead, you would probably see very little change in the overall time even though you are processing 10 times the data.

It is a common use case to use spark to reduce the size of a problem, i.e. you have lots of data, do some aggregation and get a smaller number of elements (100 in your case), then you would collect them to the driver and act directly on them instead of using spark to avoid the overheads (e.g. in your case save the result of the collect and instead of doing the foreach with println, just sum them up).

<s>One thing you can do is used coalesce(1) when you calculate pathDs. This would mean you have just 1 partition (the joining of everything would be part of the first stage). This is not too different than using the collect result except that if you want to change the limit to a larger size then coalescing to a small but not 1 value can be useful (e.g. you might do a limit of 10000 and then coalesce to 4 to still get some parallelism).</s>

**Update**

Based on the comments the result of limit is currently 1 partition so coalesce won't help (it also means there is no real reason not to do collect unless you want to use dataframe functions on the result). The process described above is still correct except that just one partition is used instead of multiple ones.

Comment: I would recommend removing the last paragraph. It is completely useless, especially  when you consider, that `pathDs` will always have 1 partition.

Comment: @zero323 is this always true? won't the number of partitions depend on the actual size of the limit and the number of keys per partition?

Comment: So in my code, I specifically did  

pathDs.cache
pathDs.collect.foreach(println)

before calculating the average, thinking that this will actually bring down the result to the driver - but it didn't seem like that's what happened. What's the proper way to collect here?

Note that if I collect and operate on the collected dataset, the results will be much faster as I'm just working on local Scala objects, but if I collect, print, and then do something else on pathDS (like in my code), it would still be 0.5 second. Is there a better way of doing caching/collecting?

Comment: @kozyr The effect of your cache + collect is to materialize the cache (you throw away the collect). When you use the head action it recalculates everything but since it is cached it skips the cached elements. You still do the aggregation inside spark. If instead you would put the collect in a variable and use that you would not use spark for it.

Comment: @AssafMendelson I guess another question then if there's a way of caching without the need for recalc?

Comment: What is your end goal? if you just need to calculate 100, save the result of pathDs.collect to a variable and work on the result in regular scala. You don't even need the caching.

Comment: That would be for the situation where I'd have maybe thousands of them (theoretically).

Comment: @AssafMendelson No, it won't. As for now it always uses `CollectLimitExec`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to optimise it is using the function `collect` that brings the entire dataset in memory and then using the canonical scala operations you can get it done in probably 1-2 ms ? But that defies the reason of using Spark in the first place.

Spark's strength is in performing distributed computation efficiently across multiple nodes on different machines. Operations on small datasets will always be more efficient without passing them through Spark. You experiment it's similar to timing a 747 that has to fly 100m. Now you are wondering why is the 747 so slow when everyone says that flying gets you around so fast.

In the old way of doing work in Spark with RDDs, around versions 1.2 -> 1.6, you could perform normal scala operations on partition data using functions like `mapPartitionsWithIndex` to avoid spark overhead. This meant of course that within that function, all the data has already been isolated at a spark node level. Using this approach you reap the benefit of the both worlds.

Comment: Thing is, I do run collect on my dataset. And I also run .cache()

Comment: Also, I'm not operating on the small dataset - this will be in TBs in production, and if counting an average of 100 numbers here is somehow dependent on my initial dataset, then this will take a lot longer than 0.5 seconds, which will be very troubling. I.e. assume this is my use case - take terabytes of GPS points, get top 100 paths, calculate some averages across those.

Answer (score -2):

1. Measure without `cache` as you loose time when loading data into`cache` itself. Could be faster.
2. Can you get `input data` into `parquet` and load it into in memory storage such as `alluxio` on the same cluster? If yes, `partition` it by `user_id`. Ideally, design architecture so that new input data is pushed into `kafka` and one `structured streaming` job appends it to `alluxio` or `cassandra` and another does aggregates on selected range. Also, give it a go with `flink` either `batch` or `stream` as it is generally faster.

if you cannot control input data structure, then focus on give 2dn stage and try using `typed aggregates`  such as:

```
   groupByKey[K: Encoder](func: T => K): KeyValueGroupedDataset[K,  
   T]
```

you will need to create data set for `csv` as:

```
case class Input(userId: String, time: DateTime) 

val ds = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", 
"true").schema(schema).csv(inputFile).as[Input]

ds.groupByKey(_.userId).avg(_.time).show
```

it will definitely be faster for large data set due to typed performance benefits but might not be for smaller one

Comment: Thing is, there are two stages here - one loads up a lot of data (don't care how long it takes), and aggregates it into 100 records. Then second stage calculates an average of a single column from these 100 records, and that takes 0.5 seconds, which is crazy slow.

Comment: I don't think this will get me any performance benefits or really explain the situation I'm seeing, where it's just the small dataset that I have an issue with.

Comment: _it will definitely be faster for large data set due to typed performance benefits_ - it definitely won't :)